# Is there anyway to dynamically change the contents of a navigation menu when a user clicks a link?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to replicate the mobile menu navigation style on asos.com in such a way that when a user clicks on Men in the navbar it loads categories under man on that navbar. I really don't know what to call it but I have been stretching my heard around how to implement same with react. Please find below an illustration on how I want it to work. Thanks

[image]

Comment: do on click menu item load categiories, ```onClick={() => { defaultFunc(); loadCategories()}}```

Comment: kindly share your code